Need to Eliminate a Loop
It's a lottery game. Each customer can have one or more ticket. The ticket has a number sequence of 6 digits. Every position can have digits 0-9.
There is lucky ticket number. Customers can get difts according to the digit matches with positions. The following code will describe the gift selection process:
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> customerTickets;
    string luckyTicket;
    int totalNumberOfTickets;

    cin>>totalNumberOfTickets;

    for(int i=0; i<totalNumberOfTickets; ++i) {
        string s;
        cin>>s; // 6 digit long string

        customerTickets.push_back(s);
    }

    cin>>luckyTicket;

    int totalGiftAmount = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<totalNumberOfTickets; ++i) {
        int match = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<6; ++j) {
            if(customerTickets[i][j] == luckyTicket[j]) match++;
        }

        if(match==6) totalGiftAmount+=100;
        else if(match==5) totalGiftAmount+=50;
        else if(match==4) totalGiftAmount+=40;
        else if(match==3) totalGiftAmount+=10;
    }

    cout<<totalGiftAmount;
}

I need to get rid of loops. Because I need to check the giftAmounts for Thousands of luckyTicket. Is it possible to calculate the gift amount in O(1) ?

"I need to get rid of loops. Because I need to check the giftAmounts for Thousands of luckyTicket." - How many thousands? What does your performance testing show at the moment, and what are your requirements? (There's no point spending time optimizing something that is already fast enough, and running that loop for even tens of thousands of tickets would complete very, very quickly.)

(I'd also note that you say you need to check it for thousands of lucky tickets - do you actually mean thousands of customer tickets? Your code can only handle a single lucky ticket. Precision in requirements is generally much more important than performance.)

Well, no, there's no real possibility of getting rid of the loop. It can be 'unrolled' and vectorised. One would still need to have a horizontal reduction of 6 independent comparisons, mapping the possible values between 0..6 to one of int amount[7]={0,0,0,10,40,50,100}; Speed should really not be an issue in this kind of a toy problem. Correctness is one thing to pursuit, and the next is readablity.

I need to calculate the totalGiftAmount in the base case of a dp approach. In this regard optimization is very necessary.

If you look at the generated code, you may see that the optimizer has automatically unrolled the loop for you.

If you mean O(1) per ticket, then your code is already doing that. If you mean O(1) overall, regardless of the number of tickets, then that's obviously impossible. If nothing else, just reading n tickets from the input stream takes O(n) time.

#include<bits/stdc++.h> and using namespace std; -- good grief, who still teaches people this nonsense?

@DanMašek "Competitive Coding" websites. Yes, I know. There's this helpful link to be added to such questions.

You can get a constant factor speedup with customerTickets.reserve(totalNumberOfTickets);

Never #include <bits/stdc++.h> and don't use using namespace std

Even with the code as it stands, I fail to understand what the problem is.  The code shown above should complete that task for "thousands" of tickets in less than a second. Why are you wasting your time trying to make it faster?


Is it possible to calculate the gift amount in O(1) ?

for(int j=0; j<6; ++j) is already O(1). There's no input value that increases the running time of this loop.
Your full solution will always be O(totalNumberOfTickets), because you have to read in totalNumberOfTickets input.

Your program indicates that winning digit should have same position in lucky ticket and a winning ticket.Order counts ?
Accepting this, why not declare a class Ticket, use it for the luckyTicket and a vector of customerTickets ? And why not use stl algorithm, a static AmountPerMatch replaces ifelseifelseif
I would code stg like this
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Ticket : public std::string {
public :
  static const std::vector<int> amountPerMatch;
  Ticket () : std::string (6, '0') {}
  Ticket (const Ticket& t) : std::string (t) {}
  ~Ticket () {}
  int match (const Ticket& t) const {
    int n (0);
    auto i (begin ()), j (t.begin ());
    for (; i != end (); ++i, ++j) n += (*i == *j)?1:0;
    return n;
  }

  int gift_amount (const Ticket& luckyticket) const {
    return amountPerMatch [match (luckyticket)];
  }
};

const std::vector<int> Ticket::amountPerMatch ({0, 0, 10, 40, 50, 100});

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  int totalNumberOfTickets;
  std::cout << "number of ticket : "; std::cin >> totalNumberOfTickets;
  std::vector<Ticket> customerTickets (totalNumberOfTickets, Ticket ());
  Ticket luckyTicket; 
  std::cout << "lucky ticket : " << std::endl;std::cin >> luckyTicket;
  std::cout << "tickets :" << std::endl;
  {
    auto i ((int) 0);
    std::for_each (customerTickets.begin (), customerTickets.end (), [&i] (auto& t) {
      std::cout << "\tticket " << i << " : " << std::endl;
      std::cin >> t;
      ++i;
    });
  }
  auto totalGiftAmount ((int) 0);
  std::for_each (customerTickets.begin (), customerTickets.end (),   [&totalGiftAmount, &luckyTicket] (const auto& t) {
    totalGiftAmount += t.gift_amount (luckyTicket);
  });
  std::cout << "TotalGiftAmount == " << totalGiftAmount << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


Observation:  Tickets have 6 decimal digits, and 6 × 10 = 60, which is less than 64.
Absurd idea:  Represent a ticket with a bit mask, compare tickets with a bitwise AND, then use popcount (which is often a single processor instruction) to determine the number of bits set, which equals the number of matching digits between the tickets.
#include <array>
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

class Ticket {
    public:
        explicit Ticket(std::string_view digits) :
            m_bitmask(make_bitmask(digits)) {}

        int matches(Ticket const &other) const {
            return std::popcount(m_bitmask & other.m_bitmask);
        }

    private:
        static std::uint64_t make_bitmask(std::string_view digits) {
            auto constexpr one = std::uint64_t(1);
            auto bitmask = std::uint64_t{0};
            for (auto const digit : digits) {
                bitmask <<= 10;
                bitmask |= one << (digit - '0');
            }
            return bitmask;
        }

        std::uint64_t m_bitmask = 0;
};

std::vector<Ticket> load_tickets(std::istream &source) {
    auto ticket_count = std::size_t{0};
    source >> ticket_count;
    std::vector<Ticket> tickets;
    tickets.reserve(ticket_count);
    std::string s;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ticket_count; ++i) {
        source >> s;
        tickets.push_back(Ticket{s});
    }
    return tickets;
}

int gift_total(std::vector<Ticket> const &tickets, Ticket lucky_ticket) {
    auto constexpr prizes = std::array<int, 7>{0, 0, 0, 10, 40, 50, 100};
    int total = 0;
    for (const auto ticket : tickets) {
        total += prizes[ticket.matches(lucky_ticket)];
    }
    return total;
}

int main() {
    auto const tickets = load_tickets(std::cin);
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    auto const lucky_ticket = Ticket{s};
    auto const total = gift_total(tickets, lucky_ticket);
    std::cout << "Total gift amount " << total << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

